# How could play a song in my computer soco python (sonos controller python)

Tags: python, sonos

I'm using soco ([link github](https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo)), I'm try to playing a song on my computer by using these command :

```
sonos = SoCo('192.168.1.102') 
sonos.play_uri('C:\\mysong.mp3')
```

but it got error :

```
Illegal MIME-Type
```

Someone help me please!

Comment: Is that the only error message? If you got a traceback, please post the full text of the traceback

Comment: thanks for your comment, i think it got error because function `play_uri` only recevice a `uri` not a 'path'. it show message 'not correct format'.I tried to get `uri` from a music file on computer but not success.

Comment: If you paste what you tried and the exact output it's likely that someone can help

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The uri you provide has to be in the Sonos upnp format.  The play_uri() action is run on your Sonos device, not on your PC, so it has no access to your local C: drive.

Play something using the Sonos app, and then use Python soco to look at the running device to get its uri as seen from the Sonos device.

```
sonos = SoCo('192.168.1.102')
sonos.get_current_track_info()
```

This will return a dict that includes the uri.  Plug that uri in to your play_uri call.

Here are some uri's that work for me.  The first is the Radio Paradise station, which should work for you.  The second is an album I have on my NAS, which gives you an idea of how to play a specific cut remotely.  The cut must be indexed in your Sonos music library.

```
sonos.play_uri('aac://http://stream-uk1.radioparadise.com/aac-320')
sonos.play_uri('x-file-cifs://192.168.1.222/SDCard_Volume1/Brian%20Eno/Thursday%20Afternoon/01.%20Thursday%20Afternoon%20(61-minute%20version).mp3')
```